# Set TCP Options on an unprivileged socket (not raw) in a Linux C program

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, setsockopt

Which TCP Options can I set for outgoing TCP packets on unprivileged socket (not raw) in a Linux C program? I refer to TCP Options in TCP Header.

I've checked http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp so for now I can add/edit:

MSS, Timestamp, Window Scale, Sack, Fast Open (see answer below)

Is there a way to add other options? I'm especially interested in Multipath but any option will be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP Fast Open can be used with the MSG_FASTOPEN flag e.g.:

```
sendto(fd, data, len, MSG_FASTOPEN, ...
```

Note that it must be supported by the server side - on Linux this can be done with:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen
```

There's a handy reference [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/508865/)

Comment: I should have googled a little more, but thank you superTyphoon.

Comment: Sorry I have not enough score to vote up. I could just accept the anwer.